# Getting first link in a soup find

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i an having a problem!
Im trying to find the source of a video using beautiful soup!

```
link = 'http://oddshot.tv/shot/dreamhackcs-20151101122251803'
r = requests.get(link)
plain_text = r.text
#print(r.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
link_source = soup.find('source', src=True, href=False)
print(link_source)
```

However it returns this:

```
<source src="https://d301dinc95ec5f.cloudfront.net/capture/dreamhackcs-20151101122251803.shot.mp4" type="video/mp4"><p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that<a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p></source>
```

Now the source for the video is in there but i don't know how i can get it to another variable to use later in my program!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace

```
print(link_source)
```

with

```
print(link_source.get('src'))
```

For more details, please check [the document](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)(the `tag.get()` part).